# Как в адаптивной сетке добавить отступ после блока, а не до?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Есть адаптивная бутстраповская сетка. Не могу разобраться как на больших экранах сделать отступ `offset-md-6` после картинки, а не до
[ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12655/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-6 image">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 summary">
      <p>his is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 summary">
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
      <p>this is sparta</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать это достаточно просто:

1. получается, что должно быть две "строки", поэтому должно быть два блока с классом `.row`;
2. добавьте в блок `.row` с картинкой фиктивный пустой блок, который будет виден только на больших экранах.

Вот [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12676/) с полным примером, а вот пример строки с `img`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 image">
        <img class="profile-pic" src="test.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 visible-md-block visible-lg-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оно сейчас так и работает для medium devices

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: виноват..перепутал местами до и после. наоборот мне нужно

Comment: как вариант закрыть row и открыть новую 
https://jsfiddle.net/vLnqLv6f/

Comment: Если нужно более гибкое решение, писать свои offset для каждого необходимого случая 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-offset-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
}